# How to load a div using jQuery after moving the focus to an input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I load a div after moving the focus into an input field? That means when my cursor is placed in an input field, I want to load a div just below the input field. Please help me, I'm newbie in jQuery and don't know exactly how can I do this.

Answer (score 2):

That's fairly straightfoward with jQuery:

```
$('#myInput').on('focus', function(){
    $(this).after('<div />').html('whatever goes in the div');
})
```

...though, where you get the contents for the div from is another issue. Do you need to load that from the server-side?

Comment: hey, faust if i want to load a html editor when i focus an input field, how can i do this?

Comment: @user3354381: if you mean, say, wire up a ckeditor instance, then just add that call in another within the function. e.g. `$(this).ckeditor();`  ... or, what else do you mean by "load an html editor" ?

Comment: faust, actually i want when i focus into an input field an editor like "ckeditor" or "redactor" will be appear, and if i wrote any thing into that editor and remove focus from input field then my wriiten text or value from editor will be appear into that input field. (sorry for my weak english, do you understand?)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( "#target" ).focus(function() {
    $( this ).after( "<div>Test</div>" );
});
```